# How the request in ASP.net is identified that its not first request and not call the Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have doubt related with the how it's identified that coming request is not first request and does not call global.asax

and who is responsible for this identification is IIS or asp.net. I am not clear about it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the IIS. IIS found that application object is already created so it uses the same object.

Comment: But an web application have many request from different source, among them some request may be the first request, so how it's identified which request is first and for which application object is created.

Answer (score 0):

It is the responsibility of the ASP.NET runtime enviornment to instantiate and call-into the `Global.asax` type, it would have some internal state to tell if it's been created yet or not. Also, `Global.asax` can be called without a HTTP request, such as IIS's "warmup" feature.